# bootstrap scrolling modal not working when a nav-tab is inside of it

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have a scrolling bootstrap `modal`. Inside of it, I used a `nav-tabs`.

the scroll function is not working, but if I remove the `nav-tabs`, the functionality comes back. any ideas?

the problem could be checked in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/minaee/gbh6jx4q/10/)

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add overflow:scroll to `modal-dialog-scrollable .modal-content` class

```
.modal-dialog-scrollable .modal-content {
    max-height: calc(100vh - 1rem);
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is , you put the `<form>` tag before modal tags!

you fidlle updated here

https://jsfiddle.net/8sjkzb30/

Comment: I checked it, The form submission won't work in this way. Thank you for your time agha mehdi

Answer (score 1):

****Try add this to your css class:****

```
 scroll {
    overflow: scroll
    overflow-x: hidden
    max-height: 850px
    }
```

it works for me....

Answer (score 0):

Add height with px in .modal-body

```
    #add_wishlist_Modal .modal-body{
  height:150px;
}
```